# Run parameterized JUnit tests with different Parameters

Tags: java, parameters, junit, annotations, scope

I have a JUnit-Test that looks like this:

```
private final User user1;
private final User user2;

public UserTest(User user1, User user2) {
    this.user1 = user1;
    this.user2 = user2;
}

@Parameterized.Parameters
public static Collection<Object[]> userData() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] {
            { new User("Tim", "Burton", "tim.burton"),
                    new User("tim", "burton", "timothy.burton") },
            { new User("Vincent", "van Gogh", "vincent.van.gogh"),
                    new User("vincent", "van-gogh", "vincent.vangogh") } });
}

@Test
public void testPositive() {
    checkMatching(user1, user2);
}
```

Now all the tests are successful, but I want to create a second List of @Parameterized.Parameters for the negative tests. The new method should look like this:

```
@Test
public void testNegative() {
    checkFalseMatching(wrongUser1, wrongUser2);
}
```

Is it possible to use a method-specific parameters? I would use the parameters I've already created for the testPositive() method and the second list of parameters for the testNegative() method.

How can I do that? Can I use a "scope" for my parameters or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple options here. First take in 3 or 4 parameters in your constructor...

```
public UserTest(User equalUser1, User equalUser2, 
          User notEqualUser1, User notEqualUser2);
```

Another option would be to use the @Enclosed running and separate the different set of Parameters / tests into separate inner classes. This is generally a good practice anyway since if you have a mix of parameterized tests and non-parameterized tests you would not want to run the non-parameterized tests multiple times.

Another option is to use Theories and to use the assumeThat method to check that the arguments are in a specific set.

[Example Theory with assumeThat](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Theories)

Comment: Thank you for suggesting multiple possibilities, that's very helpful :)

Comment: @Endosed seems to me to be the best solution for this test.

Comment: @StefanBirkner Concur

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [junitparams](https://code.google.com/p/junitparams/). With junitparams you can parameterise tests via a method that returns parameter values.